# Why am I getting this error? This error wasn't expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

Please tell me why am I getting a `Sequence index is not an int, slice, or instance with __index__pylint(invalid-sequence-index)` warning, I have provided the file code below.

```
import random
from ppwiinputs import *

print("This is PPWI\n")
end_chat = False
while end_chat == False:   
    USER_INPUT = input(">")

    if USER_INPUT.lower()  in GREETINGS:
        print(f"{GREETINGS_RESPONSE[random.randint(0,len(GREETINGS_RESPONSE)-1)]}\n")
    elif USER_INPUT.lower() in END:
        print(END_RESPONSE[random.randint(0,len(END_RESPONSE)-1)])
        quit()
    elif not(USER_INPUT.lower() in GREETINGS) or not(USER_INPUT.lower() in END):
        print("Can't find an answer to that, still learning.\n")


def grammarCorrection(USER_INPUT):
        for n in RESPONSE[range(0,len(RESPONSE)-1)]:
            for i in n:
                if (USER_INPUT in i) and (USER_INPUT != i):
                    print(f'do you mean {i}')
```

I have not tested the function yet, nor have I called it anywhere in the code. my VSCode started showing me this warning, and was curious to know what is it all about.
ppwiinputs.py file

```
GREETINGS_RESPONSE = ['HEY.', 'HOWDY.', 'WASSUP.', 'HI THERE.', "HEY, WHAT'S UP?.", 'NICE TO SEE YOU.', 'GREETINGS AND SALUTATIONS.', 'GREETINGS.']
GREETINGS = ['hi ppwi','hello ppwi','hi', 'hello']
END = ['bye', 'ok, bye', 'bye bye', 'okay bye', 'see you']
END_RESPONSE = ['BYE BYE.', 'NICE MEETING YOU, BYE.', 'BYE.', 'SEE YOU SOON.']
RESPONSE = [GREETINGS_RESPONSE, GREETINGS, END, END_RESPONSE]
```

Comment: Please paste the complete error in the question, that would contain the details on which like its throwing an error/warning.

Comment: Are you trying to skip `END_RESPONSE` from `RESPONSE` when iterating? If so, `range` isn't how you do this, you want [to slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation), e.g. `RESPONSE[:-1]` instead of `RESPONSE[range(0,len(RESPONSE)-1)]`.

Comment: Just an added suggestion, `random.choice(GREETINGS_RESPONSE)` does the same thing as `GREETINGS_RESPONSE[random.randint(0,len(GREETINGS_RESPONSE)-1)]` but in a much nicer way.

Answer (score 0):

This line `for n in RESPONSE[range(0,len(RESPONSE)-1)]:` gives the warning.

`range` is a class and returns an object that raise a warning because it is not recommended to use it as an index for a list.

To do what you want, you can simply slice the list with :

```
for n in RESPONSE[:-1]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what list you are after, but looks like you just want to iterate over list (of lists) `RESPONSE` using this line `for n in RESPONSE[range(0,len(RESPONSE)-1)]:` .
You can simply replace it with `for n in RESPONSE:` if that is the case.

Comment: Yeah, I got that idea, But I am curious, What brings that warning?

Comment: Error: Sequence index is not an int, slice.. you are trying to use range.

Answer (score 0):

First off, just to clarify. It's not a **warning**, it's an **error**. I didn't run the code calling the function, but if someone does is gonna get a TypeError. As the others answers say, it's happening because you're trying to use a **range** object to get values from a list and you can't do that because a range object creates the values of the iteration on the fly so it needs something else traverses it e.g. with a for loop to print the values unlike using slices in a list.

Besides, if you're using pylint as linter in VSCode I suggest you check [pyling messages](https://github.com/janjur/readable-pylint-messages) every time you wanna know why you're getting some warning or error and you'll understand much better what's going on. For instance, search for the error **invalid-sequence-index** says "Used when a sequence type is indexed with an invalid type. Valid types are ints, slices, and objects with an index method."

Hope this help you supporting the other answers :)